# Eliminate sudden additions/deletions in D3 basis line chart transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, interpolation, data-visualization

I have exactly similar SO question

[Eliminate sudden additions/deletions in D3 line chart transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484319/eliminate-sudden-additions-deletions-in-d3-line-chart-transition)

One difference is that, I have line interpolated as "basis"

```
var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('basis')
```

Struggling with this exactly 13 hours :/ please help

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chart</title>
        <style>
            path {
                stroke: #f00;
            }
            .line {
                stroke: #0f0;
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }
            .rule {
                stroke: #ccc;
                stroke-width: 1px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I want to get the chart below to transition such that
        the points on the lines appear to move up and down, not
        side to side.
        </p>
        <p>When transitioning to the smaller data-set especially,
        I'd like to not have a white gap appear before the lines
        take shape.
        </p>
        <p>Also, the grid-lines should slide into and out of
        existence, rather than appearing or disappearing.  Ideas?
        </p>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var data = [
            [1,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8],
            [8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        ];
        var data3 = [
            [1,1,1],
            [8,8,8],
        ];
        
        var w = 500,
            h = 100;

        var chart = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        // Add path interpolator to d3
        d3.interpolators.push(function(a, b) {
          debugger;
          var isPath, isArea, interpolator, ac, bc, an, bn, d;
        
          // Create a new array of a given length and fill it with the given value
          function fill(value, length) {
            return d3.range(length)
              .map(function() {
                return value;
              });
          }
        
          // Extract an array of coordinates from the path string
          function extractCoordinates(path) {
            return path.substr(1, path.length - (isArea ? 2 : 1)).split('L');
          }
        
          // Create a path from an array of coordinates
          function makePath(coordinates) {
            return 'M' + coordinates.join('L') + (isArea ? 'Z' : '');
          }
        
          // Buffer the smaller path with coordinates at the same position
          function bufferPath(p1, p2) {
            var d = p2.length - p1.length;
        
            if (isArea) {
              return fill(p1[0], d/2).concat(p1, fill(p1[p1.length - 1], d/2));
            } else {
              return fill(p1[0], d).concat(p1);
            }
          }
        
          isPath = /M-?\d*\.?\d*,-?\d*\.?\d*(L-?\d*\.?\d*,-?\d*\.?\d*)*Z?/;
        
          if (isPath.test(a) && isPath.test(b)) {
            isArea = a[a.length - 1] === 'Z';
            ac = extractCoordinates(a);
            bc = extractCoordinates(b);
            an = ac.length;
            bn = bc.length;
        
            if (an > bn) {
              bc = bufferPath(bc, ac);
            }
        
            if (bn > an) {
              ac = bufferPath(ac, bc);
            }
        
            // Create an interpolater with the buffered paths (if both paths are of the same length,
            // the function will end up being the default string interpolator)
            interpolator = d3.interpolateString(bn > an ? makePath(ac) : a, an > bn ? makePath(bc) : b);
        
            // If the ending value changed, make sure the final interpolated value is correct
            return bn > an ? interpolator : function(t) {
              return t === 1 ? b : interpolator(t);
            };
          }
        });
        
        function drawdata(data, chart) {
            var num = data[0].length-1;
            var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, num]).range([0,w]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h, 0]);
            
            var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('basis')
                .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d); });
            
            var flat = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
                .y(y(-1));
            
            var lines = chart.selectAll('.line')
                .data(data);
            
            lines.enter().append('path')
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .style('stroke', function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                    .attr('d', line);
            
            lines.transition()
                .ease('linear')
                .duration(500)
                .attr('d', line);
            
            lines.exit().remove();
            
            // legend
            var ticks = chart.selectAll('line')
                .data(x.ticks(num));
            
            ticks.enter().append('line')
                    .attr('x1', x)
                    .attr('x2', x)
                    .attr('y1', 0)
                    .attr('y2', h)
                    .attr('class', 'rule');
            ticks.transition()
                .ease('linear')
                .duration(500)
                .attr('x1', x)
                .attr('x2', x)
                .attr('y1', 0)
                .attr('y2', h);
            ticks.exit().remove();
        }
        var dats = [data, data3];
        function next() {
            var it = dats.shift();
            dats.push(it);
            drawdata(it, chart);
        }
        setInterval(next, 2000);
        next();
        </script>
    </body>
</html
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/xEqLBZ?editors=1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that d3 have a more clean solution. See `d3.svg.axis`.

```js
var points0 = [
    [1,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8],
    [8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
];
var points1 = [
    [1,1,1],
    [8,8,8],
];

var w = 500,
    h = 100;

var chart = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)

var color = d3.scale.category10();

function drawdata(data, svg) {
    var num = data[0].length-1;
    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, num]).range([0,w]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h, 0]);

    var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('basis')
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d); });

    var flat = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .y(y(-1));
        
    var lines = chart.selectAll('path.line')
        .data(data);

    lines
      .enter()
      .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .style('stroke', (d,i) => color(i))
          
    
    lines
    // .attr('d', line)
      .transition()
      .ease('linear')
      .duration(500)
      .attrTween("d", function(d) { return  pathTween(line(d), 4, this)})

    lines
      .exit()
      .remove();

    // legend
    var ticks = chart.selectAll('line')
        .data(x.ticks(num));

    ticks.enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('x1', w+10) // HACK
      .attr('x2', w+10) // HACK
      .attr('y1', 0)
      .attr('y2', h)
      .attr('class', 'rule')
    
    ticks.transition()
        .ease('linear')
        .duration(500)
        .attr('x1', x)
        .attr('x2', x)
        .attr('y1', 0)
        .attr('y2', h)
    
    ticks.exit().remove();
}

const data = [points0, points1]

setInterval(() => {
  const point = data[0]
  data.reverse()
  
  drawdata(point, chart)
}, 1e3);

function pathTween(d1, precision, path0) {
    var path1 = path0.cloneNode(),
        n0 = path0.getTotalLength(),
        n1 = (path1.setAttribute("d", d1), path1).getTotalLength();
    // Uniform sampling of distance based on specified precision.
    var distances = [0], i = 0, dt = precision / Math.max(n0, n1);
    while ((i += dt) < 1) {
      distances.push(i);
    }
    distances.push(1);
    // Compute point-interpolators at each distance.
    var points = distances.map(function(t) {
      var p0 = path0.getPointAtLength(t * n0),
          p1 = path1.getPointAtLength(t * n1);
      return d3.interpolate([p0.x, p0.y], [p1.x, p1.y]);
    });
    return function(t) {
      return "M" + points.map(function(p) {  return p(t); }).join("L");
    };
  }
```

```css
path {
    stroke: #f00;
}
.line {
    stroke: #0f0;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.rule {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

*Partial answer*: for the grid-lines, set an "enter" and "exit" selections using a value greater than `width`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chart</title>
        <style>
            path {
                stroke: #f00;
            }
            .line {
                stroke: #0f0;
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }
            .rule {
                stroke: #ccc;
                stroke-width: 1px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var data = [
            [0,2,3,2,8],
            [2,4,1,5,3],
        ];
        var data2 = [
            [0,1,2,3,4,5],
            [9,8,7,6,5,6],
        ];
        var data3 = [
            [1,3,2],
            [0,8,5],
        ];
        
        var w = 300,
            h = 100;

        var chart = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);

        var color = d3.scale.category10();
        
        function drawdata(data, chart) {
            var num = data[0].length-1;
            var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, num]).range([0,w]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h, 0]);
            
            var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('basis')
                .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d); });
            
            var flat = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
                .y(y(-1));
            
            var lines = chart.selectAll('.line')
                .data(data);
            
            lines.enter().append('path')
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .style('stroke', function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                    .attr('d', line);
            
            lines.transition()
                .ease('linear')
                .duration(500)
                .attr('d', line);
            
            lines.exit().remove();
            
            // legend
            var ticks = chart.selectAll('line')
                .data(x.ticks(num));
            
            ticks.enter().append('line')
            .attr('x1', w+10)
                    .attr('x2', w+10)
                    .attr('y1', 0)
                    .attr('y2', h)
                    .attr('class', 'rule')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .attr('x1', x)
                    .attr('x2', x)
                    .attr('y1', 0)
                    .attr('y2', h);
                    
          
            ticks.transition()
                .ease('linear')
                .duration(500)
                .attr('x1', x)
                .attr('x2', x)
                .attr('y1', 0)
                .attr('y2', h);
            
          ticks.exit().transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr('x1', w+10)
          .attr('x2', w+10)
          .attr('y1', 0)
          .attr('y2', h)
          .remove();
        }
        var dats = [data, data2, data3];
        function next() {
            var it = dats.shift();
            dats.push(it);
            drawdata(it, chart);
        }
        setInterval(next, 2000);
        next();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo for your time, what about chart lines?

Comment: I'll think about it. Meanwhile, let's wait and see if someone else helps you regarding this

Comment: I have added bounty

Answer (score 1):

Use Peter Beshai's [d3-line-chunked](https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-line-chunked)! It does exactly what you need: *"create lines that indicate where data is missing with gaps or differently styled chunks/line segments."*

[image]

See also the blog post where he explains various approaches to the same issue: [how to display missing data](https://bocoup.com/weblog/showing-missing-data-in-line-charts).